# GoogleAuthUtil / GoogleAccountCredential 1.17.0-rc SDK 1.8.8 API 19 does not work in android for google endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

test:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -s -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=$1"
curl -s -X GET "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=$1"
curl -s -v -X POST "https://gcl-11.appspot.com/_ah/api/rest1/0/greetings/authed" \
        -H "Authorization:  Bearer $1" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
        -d ""
```

server: https://gcl-11.appspot.com/

explorer: https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://gcl-11.appspot.com/_ah/api#p/rest1/0/rest1.greetings.authed

sourcecode: https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/

Only the 3th curl command does not work when a token from `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` is used.
Note that web client and api explorer works perfect only android does not authenticate to the endpoint server.

EDIT1:

Why does the token generated by `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` work in curl test 1 and 2 but not 3 ? If I use the token generated by the web client in https://gcl-11.appspot.com all 3 work?

When I try `credential.setSelectedAccountName(emailAccount);` it also does not give me a user at the server.

EDIT2:

I see this in the server logs

```
com.google.api.server.spi.WebApisUserService isClientIdAllowed: ClientId in token was not allowed: 522156758812-speqt3cnr7ggje0r3hhjtjg14iigru1f.apps.googleusercontent.com`
```

But the token should be allowed? (see links below)

https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/blob/master/appengine/rs/src/main/java/common/Id.java
https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/blob/master/appengine/rs/src/main/java/rest1/Greetings.java
https://github.com/gertcuykens/gcl-11/blob/master/android/src/my/endpoints/EndpointsActivity.java

EDIT3:

Turns out my pom decided not to compile my changes and uploaded the old classes... works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token you're providing in the `Authorization` header was minted for a specific client ID — that's the one you need.

This is the snippet you need to get a valid credentials object:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(
    MainActivity.this, AppConstants.AUDIENCE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(emailAccount);
```

It makes a set of assumptions:

- You're calling from a class named `MainActivity`. Replace this as necessary.
- You have a class called `AppConstants` with an `AUDIENCE` property. `AUDIENCE` should be set to the value of your web client ID.
- `emailAccount` is a valid email address of a Google account configured on the device.

Once you have this object, you should pass it into your builder (rather than using `setOauthToken`). Then you can call:

```
service.greetings().authed().execute()
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to create a correct android token please? Tried both credential and getToken but they do not give me a user object on the server.

Comment: Update question: server is ignoring my id's?